# Add application name with Twitter and Accounts frameworks

Tags: twitter, ios5, accounts

I'm developing a little Twitter application on iOS 5. I'm using Twitter and Accounts frameworks so I login in with an `ACAccount` and send tweets with `TWRequest`.

When I send a tweet, on its details, I see "via iOS". Can I set (via Twitter API or iOS frameworks) a name of application to see something like "via MyApp"?

I know that is automatically set if I authenticate via OAuth with my app consumer keys and so on, but this is not the case because I authenticate via `ACAccount`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer, on the Twitter Dev Documentation

> Some application names of iOS devices cause failover source attribution to simply "iOS" instead of the proper name of the application. This usually occurs because the application's name in the Apple Store is longer than the maximum allowed in Twitter's data model, or because an associated URL with the application is not valid.
>
> If you run into this issue ensure that:
>   * You're using a published application. Unpublished iOS apps and ad-hoc provisioned iOS apps will not utilize custom source tags.
>   * You've provided a valid URL to Apple in association with your application
>   * Your application's name is not duplicative of a name in Twitter's application database.
>
> If you don't want to wait for our bug fix:
>   * That your application's name as registered with Apple is shorter than 32 characters and is not duplicative of an application name in Twitter's database.

https://dev.twitter.com/issues/39

Comment: How are we expected to have backwards compatibility that has both 'via myapp' for both iOS5 tweets and other framework tweets? Also, what's to stop someone from registering an app on twitter that has the same name as our iphone apps, thus breaking the 'via appname' feature. This seems unscrupulously thought out.